# TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined' inside an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm beginning my path in Typescript and got a problem that i can solve. I'm trying to acess one index of one array inside the return of a API call. In the console the value is printed perfectly, but appears this message of error.

This is the interface i made :

```
    interface Data {
        list: [{
    
            main: {
                temp: number;
                temp_min: number;
                temp_max: number;
            }
    
            weather: [{
                main: string;
                description: string;
            }]
    
            clouds: [{
                all: number;
            }]
    
            dt_txt: string;
        }]
    
        dt: number;
    }
```

And that is the console.log I'm using:

```
     data?.list[1].main.temp_min
```

This is the error that appears:

> ```
> TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
>    109 |
>    110 |             <>
>  > 111 |                 {console.log(data?.list[1].main.temp_min)}
>        |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>    112 |                  {console.log(data?.list[3]?.main)} 
>    113 |
>    114 |             </>
> ```

And that is the return value from the `console.log`:

[image]

Could you guys help me?

Comment: Typescript cannot guarantee in the general case that an array access like `[1]` never fails, so it will not let you assume that it must be successful. You've defined in your interface the type of things the list can hold, but you have not specified that it cannot be empty: something like `const foo: number[] = [];` is still totally valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access the items using `?`

```
data?.list?.[1]?.main.temp_min
```

Also, update the interface like this

```
interface Data {
    list: {

        main: {
            temp: number;
            temp_min: number;
            temp_max: number;
        }

        weather: {
            main: string;
            description: string;
        }[]

        clouds: {
            all: number;
        }[]

        dt_txt: string;
    }[]

    dt: number;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just updating the interface like you sent me fixed the bug. Thanks!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

Within an array, it is not guaranteed that you will have something in index 1.

Scenarios:

```
[undefined, undefined, <object>]
[<object>]
```

When possible, best practice is not to access arrays by index directly but use a methods like '.map' or '.forEach' to programatically go through each one.

Answer (score 0):

In TS you should make sure that the data at index **i** in an array is not undefined or null in order to access the properties of that index.

So you have 2 options to fix your issue:

1. Add **?** to check if your data is undefined or not:

```js
console.log(data?.list[1]?.main?.temp_min);
```

2. Add if condition:

```js
if(data && !!data.list && data.list[1] && data.list[1].main) {
  console.log(data.list[1].main.temp_min);
}
```